# getting error in compiling in angular4

Tags: angular

component.ts

```
initForm() {

    this.newClientForm = this.fb.group({

      userCity: [null, [Validators.required]],
      userZip: [null, [Validators.required]],

     } ,

    );
  }

registerUser() {

    const newUser = this.newClientForm.value;

    this.user.user_name = newUser.userName;
    this.user.city = newUser.userCity;
}
```

in html file:

```
<section class="col col-6"> 
    <label>Select City</label> 
    <select class="form-control" name="userCity" #userCity 
            (change)="onCitySelect(userCity.value)"> 
        <option></option> 
        <option *ngFor="let city of cities" value="{{city.id}}">
            {{city.city_name}} 
        </option> 
    </select> 
</section>
```

when i register the form i am getting username but city i am getting null value i don't know what is the error in code.

Comment: "Getting null value" is not a compile error; it's a run-time error. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any model for the select dropdown for city:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" name="userCity" #userCity (change)="onCitySelect(userCity.value)">
```

Now whatever option you select, its value will be stored in the model `selectedCity`. By the way where are you invoking `registerUser` function?

Comment: in component.ts only registeruser i called

Comment: when i use [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"  it throws error

Answer (score 0):

add formControlName on your html select

```
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="city"
   name="userCity" #userCity (change)="onCitySelect(userCity.value)"> 
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" value="{{city.id}}">
        {{city.city_name}} 
    </option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

As @JayDeeEss already mentioned you need to add the appropriate `formGroup`s and `formControlName`s defined in your component to your template (html).

Also, the first `<options>` tag you used don't have a `value` attribute assigned. Refactor that to `<option value=""></option>` and also in your component, initialize the form controls value to empty string `''` instead of `null` like this,

```
this.newClientForm = this.fb.group({

  userCity: ['', [Validators.required]],
  userZip: ['', [Validators.required]],

}
```